# How to use native slots in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

I'm trying to build a simple application with react and web components UI library.
This library uses `named slots` in order to populate areas in the component.
When trying to use a named slot like this in my template:

`<div slot="app-content"></div>`

The rendered output is without the slot: `<div></div>`

Minimal reproduction:
Just add `<div slot="mySlot" id="mySlottedDiv"></div>` to a react component's template. Then inspect the resulting HTML and see that the `slot` attribute is omitted.

Here's an example of such an app: https://codesandbox.io/s/vivid-spring-hack-react-example-forked-yu9dss?file=/index.js

In this file, you can see I'm setting a `div` with `slot="app-content"` but the resulting HTML removes the attribute from the `div` - hence preventing me from using the web component's API.

Is there a way to force react NOT to remove attributes from an element? Is this a bug in react?

Comment: The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Try naming the attribute `data-slot` instead of `slot`. `slot` is not a valid attribute on a `div` element and React knows this and that's why it sanitizes it. However, any attribute starting with `data-` are valid as they're specified as custom attributes. Hopefully the web components UI library you're using handles this and treats `data-slot` the same as `slot`.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/skatejs/skatejs/issues/1096 Apparently a known issue that can be circumvented by using Preact instead. I'm wondering why you want to cram web components into a React app anyway.

Comment: @Lennholm - the `slot` attribute has been around for years now and I'm using it natively.  If what you say is true, then `react` is wrong and has a major bug in it that prevents using a valid HTML standard.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/slot

Comment: @ChrisG - thanks!
I found this one as well, but using `preact` is not an option for us.
We have our own web components library and it is web components based.
The fact react does not support valid HTML syntax is a major issue IMO.

Comment: @Lennholm, ``slot`` **IS** a valid attribute on a ``DIV``. It is React not following the standards (anymore) Facebook is stuck in a 10 year old reality; and judging by the lack of effort they put in making React18 to work with the standard, they will probably be stuck in their own reality for years to come. _React is the new Cobol_. Facebook has had years to fix this, and still scores 71% on https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/  _Or React is the new Flash, which is actually dead_

Comment: Sorry, my bad...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there are some issues opened and closed on some libraries trying to integrate with react to support `slot` attribute properly.

This seems to be a solution that circumvents react whitelisted attributes:

```
function slot(name = "") {
  return { ref: (e) => e.setAttribute("slot", name) };
}
```

and then render:

```
 <div {...slot("app-content")}>
```

This seems to work.

Here there are some more info: https://github.com/skatejs/skatejs/issues/1096
https://codesandbox.io/s/vivid-spring-hack-react-example-forked-nik1hs?file=/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Ok, apparently this is working in react version 16 and above. Here's the blog post that explains that:
https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html
In my case, it is solved by upgrading react.